# How to see full Publishing Information into custom log file

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.5

I want to create a `Custom log` in `Sitecore`

And in this log file I want to separate full Publish information in that Custom log

because we can only see item id, language version, item path, in Publishing log file and for publishing user we have to see standard log file

I want to see full publishing information into a separate custom log file.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will help, you will need to add a processor after **Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.UpdateStatistics** in **publishItem** pipeline, to include your own logs for publish information:

```cs
namespace Sitecore.OpenSource.Pipelines.Publishing
{
    public class LogPublicationInfoToCustomLog : PublishItemProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(PublishItemContext context)
        {
            LogToCustomLog(context);
        }

        private void LogToCustomLog(PublishItemContext context)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context, "context");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context.PublishOptions, "context.PublishOptions");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context.PublishOptions.SourceDatabase, "context.PublishOptions.SourceDatabase");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context.PublishOptions.TargetDatabase, "context.PublishOptions.TargetDatabase");
            Assert.ArgumentCondition(!ID.IsNullOrEmpty(context.ItemId), "context.ItemId", "context.ItemId must be set!");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context.User, "context.User");

            Database sourceDatabase = context.PublishOptions.SourceDatabase;
            Database targetDatabase = context.PublishOptions.TargetDatabase;
            ID itemId = context.ItemId;
            string userName = context.User.Name;
            Item item = context.PublishHelper.GetItemToPublish(context.ItemId);

            //Get your own custom log, for more details on how do make a custom log
            //go to http://firebreaksice.com/write-to-a-custom-sitecore-log-with-log4net/
            var logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("Sitecore.Diagnostics.MyCustomLogger");
            logger.Info("Publishing Item :" + item.Name + " : " + item.ID.ToString() + " By User : " + userName);
            //Add the rest of the details to your log here
        }


    }
}
```

Then add this to your include configs:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <publishItem>
        <processor type="Sitecore.OpenSource.Pipelines.Publishing.LogPublicationInfoToCustomLog, ASSEMBLY_NAME"
                    patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.UpdateStatistics, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
      </publishItem>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```